# Problema despliegue war Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de importar un proyecto Maven a Eclipse. Cuando intento ver todas las clases Java del proyecto,los paquetes me salen capados o bloqueados sin tener opción a ver el código tanto via Eclipse o en Explorador de archivos. Muestro una imagen del árbol de proyecto de Eclipse.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo importaste usando el wizzard de Eclipse a proyecto maven?

Comment: @DavElsanto no entiendo lo de wizzard,perdona..pero siempre lo he desplegado de la siguiente forma  File-->Import-->Web-->WAR file

Comment: ese es el problema, debes usar maven al importar el proyecto

Comment: en lugar de web busca maven project, eso debe solucionar tu problema. Probablemente se genera el error al ver que no te importa las librerías del `pom.xml`

Comment: @DavElsanto entiendo que deberia hacer File-->Import-->Maven-->Install or deploy an artifact to a Maven repository?

Comment: @DavElsanto estoy buscando que opciones tengo a la hora de filtrar por Maven project y solo me da 4 : Check out Maven Project from SCM, Existing Maven Project, Materialize Maven Binary Project y Materialize Maven Project from SCM, pero no veo como desplegar el .war en ninguna de las opciones

Comment: `Existing Maven Project`